# Jenkins regex for multiple words for negative pattern

Tags: regex, shell, jenkins, sh, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins log parser plugin to make job unstable when below string found in the jenkins console

Below two regex expressions are from a file. which tells if it finds "unknown command" or "WARNING" consider those as warning.

```
warning /unknown command/
warning /(?i)\bwarning\b/i
```

How to ignore if we find "unknown command" and WARNING in below context. In Combinations

```
[exec] ORA-0042: unknown command ")" - rest of line ignored.
[deployComposite] WARNING: Error in applying config plan: Namespace prefix 'ui' used but not declared.. Config plan was skipped.
```

pls help in two difference regex expression.

Also is there a regex tool I can use to get help from

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, those regexes are not working? The 2nd one should be written as `warning /\bwarning\b/i` I believe

Comment: first 2 regex which i currently have is also considering 3rd and 4th lines. Which I want to skip/ignore

Comment: Here is a nice tool to "visualise" your regex: https://jex.im/regulex/#!embed=false&flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24

Comment: And another one to test your regex against some text: http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 1):

To match across multiple lines, you need to

- look for the string `unknown command`
- look for *exactly one* new line character `\n` after that, i.e. skip to the next line
- use a negative look-ahead to reject the match when `WARNING` is found in the next line

Regular Expression

```
.*unknown command[^\n]*\n(?![^\n]*WARNING)
```

Here's some Java code including your example input to demonstrate:

```
String value = "[exec] ORA-0042: unknown command \")\" - rest of line ignored.\n"
        + "[deployComposite] WARNING: Error in applying config plan: Namespace prefix "
        + "'ui' used but not declared.. Config plan was skipped.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*unknown command[^\n]*\n(?![^\n]*WARNING)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Matched: " + matcher.group(0));
} else {
    System.out.println("No match!");
}
```

This will output:

```
No match!
```

If you now for example change the string `WARNING` to `DEBUG`, the output will be:

```
Matched: [exec] ORA-0042: unknown command ")" - rest of line ignored.
```